# Get Selected Items collection from a ReactiveList using ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have bound a ReactiveList Orders to a datagrid in a wpf.
I succeeded in obtaining a single selected order by following syntax

```
private Order _selectedOrder;
public Order SelectedOrder
{
    get { return _selectedOrder; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedOrder, value); }
}
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Orders.ItemChanged).Select(x => _selectedOrder = ((Order)x));
```

But if I multi select the orders in datagrid how do I get the selected items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the hint given by Gluck I found out a way to get selected orders collection by adding the selection changed event handler for the datagrid in the view as follows

In ViewModel add a reactive property

```
private IList<Order> selectedOrders;
public IList<Order> SelectedOrders
{
    get
    {
        return selectedOrders;
    }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref selectedOrders, value); }
}
```

and in the view's codebehind

```
private void OrdersGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.SelectedOrders = OrdersGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<Order>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: But wonder why ReactiveUI.Events.dll is being shipped as a separate assembly from ReactiveUI. Developers when identify this detached dll which seems useful need to request the third party software approval team again for a grant!

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to convert the `EventPattern` to an `IObservable`. You can do this using something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace System.Windows.Controls.Extensions
{
    public static class ListBoxExtensions
    {
        public static IObservable<List<T>> SelectionChanged<T>(this ListBox listBox)
        {
            return Observable.FromEventPattern<SelectionChangedEventHandler, SelectionChangedEventArgs>(
                eh => listBox.SelectionChanged += eh,
                eh => listBox.SelectionChanged -= eh)
                .Select(_ => listBox.SelectedItems.Cast<T>().ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Control`, bind the result to the `ViewModel` like this:

```cs
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl, IViewFor<MyViewModel>
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                MyListView.SelectionChanged<MyItemViewModel>()
                    .Do(list => ViewModel.SelectedItems = list)
                    .SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                    .Subscribe()
                    .DisposeWith(d);
            });
        }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get => ViewModel;
            set => ViewModel = value as MyViewModel;
        }

        public MyViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get => DataContext as MyViewModel;
            set => DataContext = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks! But how it possible that ReactiveUI.Events.WPF has no ListBox.SelectionChanged event?

Comment: @Evl-ntnt Do you have reference to ReactiveUI.Events.dll?
Try this and let me know if that worked for you: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/#hack-bindings-and-bindto

Comment: @navule No. ReactiveUI.Events was/is not yet available for .NET Core.

Comment: @movGP0 the package is available

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't seem to perform what you want, as you seem to be listening to the ReactiveList ItemChanged observable (which will trigger when your datasource changes), when what you want to watch is the grid selection.

Though not tested, the following code seems to better match what you want to achieve (using reactiveui-events helpers):

```
// in the VM
public IList<Order> SelectedOrders { /* regular RxUI property as usual */ }

// in the view
this.Grid.Events().SelectionChanged
    .Select(_ => this.Grid.SelectedItems.Cast<Order>().ToList())
    .Subscribe(list => ViewModel.SelectedOrders = list);
```

Did I grasp what you wanted to achieve ?

Comment: Your approach seems to solve the problem. But I need to add reactiveUI.events dll to the proj references. Also even after adding the reactiveui.events.dll, I didn't find SelectionChanged event on the datagrid's events collection